# Changing the default culture info of my Application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Each thread inherits the default Windows culture unless you change it
by accessing the current thread through services provided by the
System.Threading namespace.

Do you know if it possible to change the default Application culture info instead of
setting eac new thread with the culture info of its parent.

Thanks!
Ronen

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there's no application-wide setting for the default culture for new threads. The default culture of a thread is set by Windows when it is created.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with nukefusion. you have to change the culture every time thread gets initialized.

Answer (score 1):

In .NET 4.5 the CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture property was added which changes the cultureinfo of all threads in a given AppDomain.
Setting this property in the static constructor of your form should usually do the trick.

[MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentuiculture.aspx)